# spring mvc HTTP Status 404 -

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a spring hello world program in eclipse. Here is the code

index.jsp

```
<a href="hello.html">click</a>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.javatpoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

hellopage.jsp

```
Message is: ${message}
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCBasic/, I gets the index.jsp page correctly open

[image: index.jsp OutPut]

but when I click on link on the page i.e. the url http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCBasic/hello.html, I gets the error

```
HTTP Status 404 -
```

When I use url like this http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCBasic/hello, I gets this

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SpringMVCBasic/hello
```

I have taken the code from [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-3-mvc-tutorial)

Comment: You should change the link from "hello.html" to "hello" like it is defined in the controller.

Comment: try by changing the URL pattern as  <url-pattern>/*.html</url-pattern>

Comment: What is your context-path? Are you using Eclipse or Intellij Idea. Anything you see in console.

Answer (score 2):

You provided mapping for:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
```

but you have to do it for:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello.html")
```

Comment: Did you put `hellopage.jsp` into WEB-INF/jsp/ directory?

Comment: Yes, Above I mentioned the site from where I downloaded the whole project & tried to ran as it is.

Comment: have you added  Spring Core jar files and  Spring Web jar files

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the eclipse project and run it on a jboss.
Following jars needed to be included:

- spring-context
- spring-core
- spring-web
- spring-webmvc
- spring-aop
- spring-beans
- spring-expression

If i afterwards run the jboss with Java 8 all seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model in spring-servlet.xml like this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your index.jsp  instead of writing

```
href="hello.html">
change to
href="./hello.html">
```

and

In `HelloworldController.java` instead of writing

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
```

change to:-

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/hello.html")
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add all these jar as external jar or add these jar to your lib folder

[Spring Jar](http://www.javatpoint.com/src/sp/springjars.zip)

Comment: I already added all the spring framework 4.1.1 JAR files via the properties of eclipse.